# Flour Tortilla for Passover

Tags: passover

Recently, my brother asked me this question. Hypothetically, are flour tortilla, which are not made with yeast, kosher for Pesach?

I was told flour tortillas are only made with flour and water. How are they different from matzah?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Chametz is a problem even without yeast. Flour and water makes chametz unless it's baked in the proper way.

Comment: Are they made l'shem mitzvas matzah?

Comment: To @robev's point, baking yeast as we know it was only isolated in the last 200 years. Before that people used flour water and by default whatever natural yeast was in the environment. It may take longer but unless you're in sterile laboratory conditions, it will rise.

Answer (score 4):

As long as all of the relevant halakhoth are properly observed in its preparation (the flour used, the water used, the duration of time spent kneading and baking, etc.), there are many traditional/ethnic flatbreads (such as flour tortillas) that *could* qualify as masah.

Given the many difficulties involved in practically observing these halakhoth, there are very few today that find it advisable to attempt to do so independently. That said, there is no prohibition in doing so provided one scrupulously adheres the halakhic guidelines.